# SQL 2012 Management Studio - "Script Table as"

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

In SQL 2008 Management Studio, when you right click on a table in object explorer and say "Script Table as" - "Drop to " etc, the generated script used to have an `IF EXISTS` check before the `DROP` statement.

I appears that SQL 2012 Management Studio no longer has this. I did a perfunctory online search on this, as well as looked at the "Options" menu and couldn't find any thing about this feature removal.

Is it possible to get this back somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's optional now, and turned off by default.

Here's how to turn it on again:  In Mgmt Studio 2012, you can find the option under Tools -> Options; select SQL Server Object Explorer -> Scripting in the left pane; set **Check for object existence** in the right pane to **True**.